# How to add custom code rules to stylecop in xamarin studio?

Tags: c#, xamarin, stylecop, static-code-analysis

I created a library project in xamarin which has a simple rule called "MyCustomAnalyzer".

Now i added this .dll in packages/StyleCop.MSBuild.4.7.55.0/tools folder of my New project where other default csharp .dll's are present. Stylecop is not recognizing this customly created dll and is running only default stylecop rules.

can anyone tell me how to get this done ?